# Show that the polynomial $p(z)=z^5+7z-1$ (in $\Bbb{C}[z]$) has one real root with absolute value smaller than one.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Show that the polynomial $p(z)=z^5+7z-1$ (in $\Bbb{C}[z]$) has one real root with absolute value smaller than one and that the rest of the roots are in $\{1<|z|<2\}$.

Ok, so this exercise is in the context of residues, Rouche's Theorem, etc. But I don't even know how to start. Where to start? How can I apply Rouche (If that is what I should do)!

Comment: Check out this example, and google some others of applications of Rouche's theorem and the argument principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Usage

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272007/find-the-number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-using-rouches-theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do one part, and hopefully you can use that as a guide to the other. Consider $|7z|$. For $|z|=1$, $|p(z)|+|7z|>|7z|=7>|z^5-1|=|(p(z)-7z|$. Thus $p(z)$ and $7z$ have the same number of roots inside the circle of radius $1$, namely $1$.