# Why is only the boundary considered when using Rouche's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

A typical setup for a Rouche's Theorem problem is one where you have a polynomial, say $f(z)$, defined on some domain $U$. For simplicity let's take $U$ to be the unit disk. What often happens is one splits up $f(z)$ into $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ such that $|g(z)| > |h(z)|$ for all $z \in U$, and then based on the zeros of $g(z)$ one can make conclusions about the number of zeros of $f(z) = g(z) + h(z)$.

What has been causing me some doubt is how the condition $|g(z)| > |h(z)|$ for all $z \in U$ is shown. Based on the examples I have seen one shows this inequality by using the triangle inequality and the maximum values of $g(z)$ and $h(z)$, which of course happens on the boundary of the domain. However, how do we know that the inequality still holds *within* the domain? Why does it suffice to only check the boundary?

An example: [Find the number of roots of a polynomial using Rouche's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272007/find-the-number-of-roots-of-a-polynomial-using-rouches-theorem).

Comment: You need **strict** inequality, this is an essential requirement. There is a little diagram in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem that might illustrate.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks I edited the inequalities in my post. I am still unsure about showing the inequality within the boundary however.

Comment: It seems that you believe that having $|g(z)|>|h(z)|$ for all $z\in U$ is a hypothesis of Rouché's theorem, but it isn't: the hypothesis is that $|g(z)|>|h(z)|$ for all $z$ on the boundary of $U$, which is therefore all that needs to be checked.

Comment: The point of Rouche is that for a holomorphic function that is non zero on a (nice enough) Jordan curve, the number of zeroes (in the domain) inside the curve depends only on the change of argument of $f$ around the curve and this (being an integer) is invariant under a homotopy through holomorphic functions that keep being non zero on the curve; the condition $|g(z)|>|h(z)|$ on the curve ensures that $g+th$ is such between $g, g+h=f$

Comment: @GregMartin Yes that was exactly it, my fault for not reading close enough. Thanks!